# Where do PHP file corresponding to a twig files are stored in drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

This is a portion of  page.html.twig file

```
<div class="content col-lg-{{ page.main_content_width }} col-md-{{ page.main_content_width }} col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      {{ page.highlighted }}

      {{ title_prefix }}
      {% if title %}
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
      {% endif %}
      {{ title_suffix }}

      {{ tabs }}

      {% if action_links %}
        <nav class="action-links">{{ action_links }}</nav>
      {% endif %}

      {{ page.content }}


      {{ feed_icons }}
</div>
```

There is no block region named as **highlighted** in the theme.
Where is these variables are stored.I cant find a php template file for this twig file

Comment: Well there is no block region in this twig either. It just display the `highlighted` variable content.

Comment: Regions are defined in your THEME.info.yml file if that is what you're asking.

Comment: he is asking where the variable are being set and passed on to `twig`. In which `PHP` file to be exact

Comment: @DarkBee exactly

Answer (score 0):

These variables are generated with renderable array and you can always alter/see them in the respective preprocess hooks. In your case `hook_preprocess_page` will show you all the variables used in the twig.

And to answer to your where these values are set, in the file `/core/includes/theme.inc` `function template_preprocess_page` is preparing those variables.

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $language_interface = \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage();
  foreach (\Drupal::theme()
    ->getActiveTheme()
    ->getRegions() as $region) {
    if (!isset($variables['page'][$region])) {
      $variables['page'][$region] = array();
    }
  }
  $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
  $variables['front_page'] = \Drupal::url('<front>');
  $variables['language'] = $language_interface;

  // An exception might be thrown.
  try {
    $variables['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')
      ->isFrontPage();
  } catch (Exception $e) {

    // If the database is not yet available, set default values for these
    // variables.
    $variables['is_front'] = FALSE;
    $variables['db_is_active'] = FALSE;
  }
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()
    ->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['node'] = $node;
  }
}
```